# How to set pen color in Tinymce WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: knockout.js, tinymce, editor

I´m using the tinymce editor plugin. I introduce my text as a knockout function in viewModel:

```
self.myText = ko.observable("bla bla bla bla bla");
```

my HTML is:

```
<textarea id="Textarea1"  data-bind="tinymce: myText, tinymceOptions: { 
     plugins : 'wordcount,noneditable'
     ,theme_advanced_buttons2 : ''
     ,theme_advanced_buttons1 : ''
     ,resize: 'both'
     }" style="width:100%; height: 700px">
</textarea>
```

This works fine. 
However I want the user to be able to edit the text so that I can track the changes in a simple way. there are several issues here. But first I was hoping there was a way to set the "pen" color when opening the editor so that the existing text remains the way it is (black), but new text is colored blue.

Also would be nice if deleting of text would introduce a red strikethrough instead of actual 
deleting.

I haven´t been able to find these options in the documentation, but maybe it could be done in the in the update part customized binding?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().tinymceOptions || {};

        function writeModelValue(ed) {
            var modelValue = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                modelValue(ed.getContent());
            }
        }

        //handle edits made in the editor
        options.setup = function (ed) {
            ed.onChange.add(writeModelValue); //on add undo point
            ed.onKeyUp.add(writeModelValue); //on add undo point
            ed.onUndo.add(writeModelValue); //on undo
            ed.onRedo.add(writeModelValue); //on redo
        };


        $(element).tinymce(options);

        //handle destroying an editor 
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).tinymce().remove();
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value !== $(element).html()) {
            $(element).html(value);
        }

        // Do something smart here…?


    }
};
```